# Microsoft has acknowledged that Windows update KB4532693 contains serious problems. So why does Windows still download it?

Tags: windows-10

There are multiple articles available on the Internet relating how Microsoft has acknowledged that there are multiple, serious issues with their Windows 10 update KB4532693.  Here's one of them:

https://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-confirms-major-windows-data-deletion-bug-sort-and-offers-awkward-fix

If this update is problematic, and if Microsoft acknowledges that it's problematic, then why is KB4532693 still downloading when Windows checks for updates?  And, should I let Windows apply this update?

Comment: It does not affect every machine, and also, Microsoft could have fixed the update. It is not causing any issue on my machine and the install date was Feb 12 which I think was after the original update.

Comment: Files were never deleted, default profile was being loaded, making it appear files were gone.  [Microsoft has yet to acknowledge the issue.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903)

Answer (score 1):

> There are multiple articles available on the Internet relating to how Microsoft has acknowledged that there are multiple, serious issues with their Windows 10 update KB4532693.

Microsoft at this time has not actually acknowledged any issues with [KB4532693](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4532693).

> If this update is problematic, and if Microsoft acknowledges that it's problematic, then why is KB4532693 still downloading when Windows checks for updates?

The reason the update is still being offered is due to the fact Microsoft has not actually removed the update.  `KB4524244` was the update that was removed.  I should point out, if you are affected by the bug, your data is not actually deleted. Windows is simply loading into a temporary profile.

Source: [Windows 10 KB4532693 Update Bug Hides User Data, Loads Wrong Profile](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-kb4532693-update-bug-hides-user-data-loads-wrong-profile/)

> Should I let Windows apply this update?

You are the only one that can decide if you should install the update.  If you are worried I would just wait till the next patch.  There is a good chance this profile bug is due to a known incompatability with Avast and AVG Antivirus products.

Sources:

- [Known issues - Windows 10 version 1903](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903#known-issues)[3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903#known-issues)
- [Known issues - Windows 10 version 1909](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903#known-issues)[3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903#known-issues)

Comment: The linked article claims Microsoft responded but the article fails to provide the response they received.   Given the page that lists all issues Windows 10 has currently doesn’t include this issue I stand by the fact Microsoft actually has not acknowledged it.